# Dynamic, ever-changing list of method delegates

Tags: c#

I have an ever-changing SQL table of component type names. Nothing is ever deleted from it, nor do any records ever get altered, rows are just added to this table.

These component type names represent custom components available on specific websites, and all these components are rendered in different manners by individual methods. Every component has it's own method for rendering.

Rather than having to make sure that there is an enum in my component rendering library that is at all times kept up to date with the rows in the database, I wish to somehow generate an enumerable of delegates, actions or whatever is preferable named as the component type name,  based on the rows of the SQL table, referring to the rendering method of the corresponding component.

This library is used on varius sites and the rendering methods often differ from site to site.

My goal is to create easily maintainable code and detect which component type names have unimplemented rendering methods whenever a row is added to the SQL table. An unimplemented method would indicate that I've forgotten to do my job, as the method would be implemented at the same time as the SQL row is added to the table. This kind of exception detection would serve mainly as a reminder to myself.

What would the recommended manner of approach be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some kind of automated integration test, that goes through the table and tries to find corresponding class/delegate for each row would probably work best.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! How would you search for a class/delegate?

Comment: @Maritim Simplest would be some kind of collection of all of them with some way to identify each with specific row. Or you can use reflection across all types in assembly and look for types that implement specific interface/have specific signature.

Comment: I get the feeling that the matter of populating this collection would defeat the purpose, who/what would decide which delegate is connected to which row?

Comment: This lead me down the path of reflection and I managed to solve it. Thanks Euphoric!